# Mate 16.04.1 and western digital mybookworld NAS not talking

Tags: 12.04, 16.04, mount, mate, nfs

I'm upgrading my main machine from 12.04 LTS to Mate 16.04.1.  I use a Western Digital (white light) NAS on my network.  It works fine on 12.04 but it won't mount to 16.04.  Here's what I know so far.

On 12.04, here is what mount does

```
/etc/fstab entry
10.1.0.3:/nfs/Public   /media/public  nfs     nolock,rw,hard,intr                     0 0
```

(note: the above entry works on my existing 12.04 machine)

```
$> sudo mount /media/public



jgd@John-laptop:~$ sudo mount -v /media/public
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sat Nov 12 13:05:43 2016
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nolock,hard,intr,vers=4,addr=10.1.0.23,clientaddr=10.1.0.23'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 10.1.0.23:/nfs/Public
jgd@John-laptop:~$
```

Now here's the interesting part.  If I mount from the command line

```
jgd@John-laptop:~$ sudo mount -v 10.1.0.3:/nfs/Public /media/public
```

I get the following

```
jgd@John-laptop:~$ sudo mount -v 10.1.0.3:/nfs/Public /media/public
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sat Nov 12 13:15:36 2016
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=10.1.0.3,clientaddr=10.1.0.23'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=10.1.0.3'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 10.1.0.3 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 10.1.0.3 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 773
jgd@John-laptop:~$
```

**SUCCESS**

So my question is, what do I put in /etc/fstab to cause mount.nfs to duplicate the command line behavior?

Thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

Your mount debugs have your answer: the very first command only tries to mount some nfs v4 share. The last command fails mounting using v4, then falls back to v3.

In your fstab, try adding `nfsvers=3`. fstab entry should look like:

```
10.1.0.3:/nfs/Public /media/public nfs nolock,rw,hard,intr,nfsvers=3 0 0
```

Also, you may want to consider using `autofs` handling network shares. As root:

```
apt-get install autofs4
cat <<EOF >/etc/auto.master
+dir:/etc/auto.master.d/
+auto.master
EOF
mkdir /etc/auto.master.d
cat <<EOF >/etc/auto.master.d/nfs
localname -rw nfs.server.ip:/path/to/share
EOF
cat <<EOF >/etc/auto.master.d/nfs.autofs
/media/localname/ /etc/auto.master.d/nfs --ghost --timeout 43200
EOF
service autofs restart
ls -l /media/localname/*/ #would force mounting NFS share
ls -l /media/localname/ #should show your remote share
```

Such is preferred dealing with NFS shares, as these may go away, come back, ... Autofs is a nice way to cope with these.

Comment: I  tried nfsvers=3.  The debug messages inlcuded "...,nfsvers=3,nfsvers=4,...

Comment: Let me try this again.  I  tried nfsvers=3.  The debug messages inlcuded "...,nfsvers=3,nfsvers=4,...

The next problem is that autofs4 isn't on the machine nor in the repositories because "sudo apt-get install autofs4" fails.  I did install autofs.

Your scripts sorta work.  They mount /media/public after a looong wait but I get the error message "ls: cannot access 'public/public/': No such file or directory" after I execute "ls /media/public/*/.

Comment: continuing previous comment...

I'd really like to get this to work with /etc/fstab.  The problem with autofs is that something has to do something to the mount point before it mounts.  File manager doesn't show the NFS share until I do something from a shell prompt.  I guess that I could add a startup script that does something like

    ls /media/public >/dev/null

But this is getting way too complicated, especially since I have to deploy the solution to several machines to be upgrades once we figure out the simple solution.

Comment: I'm not clear: what is the message showing when editing your fstab? Why would nfsvers=4 show in the error message? As for autofs: indeed, if you need your shares always mounted, then some cron job could be necessary.

Comment: for the fstab entry of 
` 10.1.0.23:/nfs/Public                            /media/public               nfs     nolock,rw,hard,intr,nfsvers=3                    0 0`

the debug output is 

`

Comment: `
`root@John-laptop:/etc# mount -v /media/public
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sun Nov 13 15:53:25 2016
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nolock,hard,intr,nfsvers=3,addr=10.1.0.23'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 10.1.0.23 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 10.1.0.23 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 35667
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 10.1.0.23:/nfs/Public
root@John-laptop:/etc# `

Comment: The output is different this time.  The only thing that has changed is that I installed the NFS server on this machine.  That shouldn't matter on the client machine but it did.

what is the `prog 1000005` item.  I haven't been able find out what that is.  I have about 2 days in this now and I'm out of guesses.